# Showing $g(A \cap B)g^{-1} = g(A)g^{-1} \cap g(B)g^{-1}$ in a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $g \in G$, and $A \cap B$ are subgroups. Is the following true?

$$g(A \cap B)g^{-1} = g(A)g^{-1} \cap g(B)g^{-1}$$

I managed to prove that $g(A \cap B)g^{-1} \subseteq g(A)g^{-1} \cap g(B)g^{-1}$, but am missing something in the reverse direction.

Comment: That seems obvious and has nothing to do (directly) with groups: conjugation is an automorphism; hence is bijective, and the formula is true for any bijection of a set into another set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the reverse: suppose that $x\in gAg^{-1}\cap gBg^{-1}$. Then we can write $x=gag^{-1}$ for some $a\in A$, but can also write it as $x=gbg^{-1}$ for some $b\in B$.

Note, however, that $gag^{-1}=gbg^{-1}$ if and only if $a=b$ (multiply on the left by $g^{-1}$ and the right by $g$). Hence $a\in A\cap B$, so that $x=gag^{-1}\in g(A\cap B)g^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, really clear!

Answer (score 2):

We have $x\in gAg^{-1}\cap gBg^{-1}$ iff $x\in gAg^{-1}\land x\in gBg^{-1}$ iff there exist $a\in A, b\in B$ such that $x=gag^{-1}=gbg^{-1}$, which happens iff $a=b\in A\cap B,$ so that $x\in g(A\cap B)g^{-1}$.